# Physical volume control buttons assigned to iOS app buttons

Tags: ios, iphone

I have two buttons in my iOS project. Is there anyway to assign the volume up/ down on the physical device itself to my application buttons so when the volume button is pressed, it controls the buttons? Thank you

Comment: Im confused, Are you asking if you can add UIButtons to control the volume of an iPhone?

Comment: Your app will be rejected, as that would violate the human interface guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

No that's not possible. Also why would you do that to a user? If I was a user and you override those buttons when I expected them to change the volume, you app would be deleted, very quickly.

Comment: Well, one example of this sort of 'misuse' is the camera app on iPhones: pressing a volume button will take a picture.

Comment: Thats expected and a welcome behaviour.

Comment: I agree, so obviously sometimes this behavior is okay. It's just a design decision.

Comment: My point is, 3rd party devs should not have that level of access to an iDevice.

Comment: Why shouldn't they have that level of access? I would say that it's a design decision that can be made correctly by third parties just as much as by a first parties.

Comment: because APPLE SAID SO.  There are plenty of things that they do in their own software but which they have forbidden to their third party developers.  There is nothing you can do about it if you want to distribute software on their platform through their repository. the hardware buttons are theirs not ours